# Facebook OpenGraph API action when posting creates 2 entries in activity log instead of 1

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

In my facebook application I have my custom object 'Level' and my custom action 'Complete'. Also I created a story with that action and object for my application. When user completes a level I create an instance of Level, take ID of that instance from response and post Complete action with that ID. But in Activity Log there is 2 entries. The first seems right: "User completed SampleLevel in MyFBApp", but there is also second entry: " User posted SampleLevel in MyFBApp". And I can't understand why this 'Post' action appears in Activity Log. I didn't configure any 'Post' actions connected to my 'Level' object, and I don't post anything like that from my app. 
Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what is wrong with this workflow. When I create object through application with user access token, I create user owned object and this activity automatically appears in user activity log as 'Post' action. In my case I need application owned objects, and it could be done with application access token or by using self-hosted objects. Question closed.