# Facebook OpenGraph iOS:Create app-owned object to avoid posting 2 entries in activity log

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've created app-owned object to avoid posting 2 entries in activity log as stated by this link [Facebook OpenGraph API action when posting creates 2 entries in activity log instead of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299739/facebook-opengraph-api-action-when-posting-creates-2-entries-in-activity-log-ins)
But when I set User_Generated flag to 'true' to post large image instade of thumbnail image, it failed, if i post user-owned object and set User_Generated to ‘true’, it works. Could someone tell me what's happened here, I just want to post fb opengraph story with large image and avoid display 2 entries in activity log.